# Insert Iterators vs container's member function inserter

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, inserter

I've been studying stl for the past two weeks and been dealing with alot of `vector<T>`, `deque<T>`, and `list<T>`. All those times I've been using `push_back()`, `push_front()`, `insert()`. Currently though, I've been introduced to **"Insert Iterators"** which are the following:

- `back_insert_iterator`, which is similar to `push_back()` and does requires the container to have a `push_back()` function to work
- `front_insert_iterator`, which is similar to `push_front()` and requires the container to have a `push_front()`
- `insert_iterator`, similar `insert()` and blah blah blah

So I know how to implement all of this. My question is quite simple, what is the difference? Why bother using the **Insert Iterators**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you can pass them to algorithms, e.g.

```
std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));
```

Comment: somes simple enough, the teacher should've just said it explicitly and instead of being an old implicit mercurial laskasjflasjdf.

Comment: It's always better to make things clear, yes :) The bottom line is that `back_insert_iterator` is "just" an output iterator that calls `push_back` in its assignment operator (e.g. see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/back_insert_iterator/). If you're interested, I seem to remember Josuttis' book "The C++ Standard Library" having a more detailed explanation of all of this.

Comment: I will buy that book in my next paycheck :)

Comment: There's a new version just out actually :)